# Proving there are infinitely many different natural numbers such that $a^2+b \mid a+b^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Prove that there are infinitely many different natural number so that 
$a^2+b \mid a+b^2$.

Comment: Do you mean $a\ne b$ with different? Or do you mean different pairs $(a,b)$ of natural numbers? In the second case the statement is trivial.

Comment: Yes my mean is $a \ne b$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you regard $0$ as a natural number?

Comment: You should edit a few successful pairs $(a,b)$ into the question body.

Comment: No. I have a way solution.  if $a^2+b|b^2+a$ then we a bit calculations we have $b=a^4-a^2+a$

Comment: So... mission accomplished?

Comment: Yes thanks. So I remove this question.

Comment: What have you tried?  I would first make a spreadsheet and find some examples.  One way to prove this is to show that given an $(a,b)$ pair you can find a greater $(a',b')$ pair.  Your last comment is not correct.  $(2,5)$ and $(3,5)$ both work, but neither one satisfies your equation.  Your condition is sufficient, however, which solves the problem.

Comment: @Sara.Beytasi Instead of closing, you may consider posting your finding as (self-)answer

Comment: In my opinion, you should post a second question, similar to this one, but insisting that *a* and *b* be coprime.

Answer (score 1):

Examples with $b \leq 100$

```
 a     b
 2     5
 3     5
 4    10
 5    10
 3    12
 8    12
 2    14
 5    17
 3    19
 5    20
 6    26
11    27
10    30
 3    33
 4    36
 7    37
 5    38
12    38
10    43
 8    44
 5    45
27    48
 4    49
 8    50
10    54
24    56
 6    57
17    62
 5    65
 9    65
17    68
23    69
27    69
 3    75
11    77
 5    80
10    82
12    84
 8    88
17    89
```

Comment: A way solution is, if $a^2+b|a+b^2$ then we have $a^2+b|a^4+a$ so for proving that existence of infinitely many solutions it is sufficient we consider $a^2+b=a^4+a$

Comment: [Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PCjI8.png) are the solutions for $a,b\le10^3$ with *a* and *b* coprime.